# Add additional implementation while doing logout in spartacus extending AuthService

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Want to add a custom logic while doing logout. Have created customAuthService extending AuthService rewrite logout method, but how can I use  UserToken and AuthSelectors ? not able to import the same from @spartacus/core

Answer (score 0):

could you please provide more about your concrete use case?

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(client: AuthService) {

    client.getUserToken().subscribe((token) => console.log('user token: ', token));

    client.getOccUserId().subscribe((id) => console.log('id: ', id));

    client.getClientToken().subscribe((clientToken) => console.log('Client token: ', clientToken));

    client.getClientToken().subscribe((clientToken) => console.log('Client token: ', clientToken));


    client.isUserLoggedIn().subscribe((logged) => console.log('user logged? ', logged));

    client.authorize('1', '2');

   }
 }
```

Just inject AuthService and you can use UserToken from its method getUserToken.

Best regards,
Jerry